# Magento 2 checkout page Error on checkbox My billing and shipping address are the same function () { return Math.max.apply(null, this); } error

Tags: magento2, checkout, address, billing, street-address

On checkout page while checkbox is checked I am getting error function () {return Math.max.apply(null, this);}

this error is coming after the Street Address value and displayed after street address.

In source I can check it is rendering after this code below

<! -- ko text: _.values(currentBillingAddress().street).join(', ') -->

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment bellow code in animation.transition.end.js file.

file path: "/app/design/frontend/Olegnax/athlete2/web/js/animation.transition.end.js"

```
//Array.prototype.max = function () {
//  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
//};
```